# Кроссбраузерные приложения

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript

Настанет ли тот день когда-нибудь, когда для каждого браузера не придется писать свойственный только ему javascript-код?

Comment: Крик души. ) Я думаю валить из веба уже, ибо с этими идиотскими хромами-нихромами-сафарями уже проще флэш лепить, чем кроссбраузерно верстать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рано или поздно такой день настанет. Но ждать его придется еще долго: надо сначала, чтобы производители браузеров приняли стандарт, а потом дождаться отмирания несоответствующих стандарту браузеров. Если с первым условием все понятно - производители и так стремятся нивелировать несоответствия между браузерами, то выполнению второго будут препятствовать сами пользователи. Скажите, давно вы видели при создании сайта в тексте задания, к примеру, "поддержка IE6/7"? Пользователи еще используют этих динозавров, поэтому создателям сайтов еще приходится считаться с ними, что, в свою очередь, продлевает срок жизни старых браузеров. Выход? В зависимости от браузера выводить на сайте сообщение (css-хаками, js или редиректами) типа "обновите браузер по ссылке...". Да, это будет потеря клиентов, но это будет и небольшим вкладом в развитие веба.

Все вышенаписанное является личным мнением и не претендует на развязывание холивара.

Answer (score 2):

Различия в браузерах есть прямое следствие конкуренции между ними. Каждый производитель стремится сделать что-то свое, чтобы обойти соперника. В тот момент, когда все производители делают нечто, что изначально было создано пионером, возникает потребность стандарта (поскольку отличия уже не дают конкурентного преимущества), который либо навязывается пионером, либо создается по общему соглашению. Соответственно, массовая стандартизация придет, когда конкуренция ослабнет: появится лидер рынка (с долей в, например, 90%) или техническое развитие веба замедлится.

В практическом плане решением кросс-платформенности является создание библиотек-прослоек, которые берут на себя реализацию платформенно-зависимого кода. Для современого веба наиболее распространенной считается jQuery.

Comment: +1 пока нет единого стандарта, не будет и совместимости.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery вроде решает эту проблему.